# How do i send an object from Angular to an Asp.net Web Api?

Tags: angular, typescript, asp.net-web-api2

I have the exception in my Web Api

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

The data in the object is printed on to the console but it is not passed to the Api Controller. The object ae s "null"

**This is my controller:**

```
[Route("api/AddMovie")]
[HttpPost]
public int AddMovie([FromBody]Movie movie)
{
   int check = objMovie.AddMovie(movie);
   return check;
}
```

AddMovie is the function i created to store data in database.

**This is my component:**

```
import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';
import { slideInOutAnimation } from 'src/app/animations';
import { Movie } from 'src/app/movie';
import { NgxSpinnerService} from 'ngx-spinner';
import { MovieServiceService } from 'src/app/Service/movie-service.service';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { formatNumber } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-addmovie',
  templateUrl: './addmovie.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./addmovie.component.css'],
  // make slide in/out animation available to this component
  animations: [slideInOutAnimation],

  // attach the slide in/out animation to the host (root) element of this component
  // tslint:disable-next-line: no-host-metadata-property
  host: { '[@slideInOutAnimation]': '' }
})
export class AddmovieComponent implements OnInit {

  // tslint:disable-next-line: new-parens
  movie = new Movie;
  fileData: File = null;
  addMovieForm: FormGroup;


  constructor( 
    private spinner: NgxSpinnerService,
    public fb: FormBuilder,
    private http: HttpClient,
    public movieService: MovieServiceService) {
    this.addMovieForm = this.fb.group ({
      movieName: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(1)]),
      releaseDate: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
      releaseYear: new FormControl('' , [Validators.required]),
      certification: new FormControl('' , [Validators.required]),
      runtime: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
      rating: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.max(10)]),
      moviePlot: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(1)]),
      cast: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(1)]),
      imageName: new FormControl('', [Validators.required])
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  onFileSelect(event) {
    if (event.target.files.length > 0) {
      const file = event.target.files[0];
      this.addMovieForm.get('imageName').setValue(file);
    }
  }
  public onSubmit() {
    debugger;
    // tslint:disable-next-line: prefer-const
    let movieForm = this.addMovieForm.value;
    this.movie.movieName = movieForm.movieName;
    this.movie.releaseDate = movieForm.releaseDate;
    this.movie.releaseYear = movieForm.releaseYear;
    this.movie.certification = movieForm.certification;
    this.movie.runtime = movieForm.runtime;
    this.movie.review = movieForm.rating;
    this.movie.moviePlot = movieForm.moviePlot;
    this.movie.cast = movieForm.cast;
    this.movie.imageName = movieForm.imageName;
    console.log(this.movie);
    this.http.post('http://localhost:50686/api/AddMovie', this.movie).subscribe(
      (res) => console.log(res),
      (err) => console.log(err)
    );
}
}
```

Comment: Then the issue is at the controller side. It is not able to match certain property(s) which causes "Object reference not set to an instance of an object". Match the request params with the model at controller.

Comment: Sounds like `objMovie` is null.

Comment: No, i have declared ```objMovie``` at the starting of the class.

Comment: chek the sintax when declare movie, it's: `movie = new Movie()` -see the parenthesis-. I like this `[fromBody]` you has, but I'm not sure if is a attribute necesary in your web API -depending the version of ASP.NET- try remove -it's only a idea just in case

Comment: I removed ```[FormBody]``` it worked, but the error is the image uploader. The object is passed when i do not upload any image. I will try to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are invoking the api call without any header.
Try the following

```
const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      })
    };
this.http.post('http://localhost:50686/api/AddMovie', this.movie, httpOptions)
.subscribe(
      (res) => console.log(res),
      (err) => console.log(err)
    );
```

Comment: Tried it but doesn't work. Still the the movie object is null.

Comment: @Varum, by defect, httpClient send data in type 'application/json', so it's not necesary

Answer (score 0):

The error says that your object `Movie` is null. It means that you haven't initialized your object yet or you have set it to null. In this case you can do the following,

1. To initialize the object before you use it,

   ```
   Movie movie = new Movie();
   ```
2. Check for null before you use the object instance,

   ```
   public int AddMovie([FromBody]Movie movie)
   {
       if (movie != null) {
           // Do something with movie
       }
   }
   ```
3. Handle the `null` and throw a suitable exception,

   ```
   public int AddMovie([FromBody]Movie movie)
   {
       if (movie == null) {
           throw new Exception("Custom exception message");
       }
   }
   ```